# Managing hiding/showing multiple keyboards in Xcode and swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have got total 3 textfields in my screen, and I am trying to move my view up when the keyboard pop up by adjusting the y coordinate using the notification, the code looks like this

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    subscribeToKeyboardNotifications()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications()
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    view.frame.origin.y -= getKeyboardHeight(notification)
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    view.frame.origin.y += getKeyboardHeight(notification)
}

func getKeyboardHeight(notification: NSNotification) -> CGFloat {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue // of CGRect
    return keyboardSize.CGRectValue().height
}

func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:"    , name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:"    , name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}
```

It is working correctly partially, when I click on the textbook, the keyboard pops up and it moves the screen up, and when I tap or press return, it moves it down.

However, there is one scenario where it breaks. Lets say I click on the text box and it opens the keyboard, then I click on another text box. The keyboardWillShow method gets called again and there is black patch in my screen. Why is keybaordWillShow method getting called again without keyboardWillHide method, in this case(when I click on textbox2 directly after clicking textbox1)?

Comment: I think the problem is with the way you handle the observers..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can control your selector functions like this. ( I assume that you don't need to control view's coordinate for your first two textfields since the keyboard doesn't hide them when it shows up.)

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {

      if( thirdTextField.isFirstResponder()){
          view.frame.origin.y = -getKeyboardHeight(notification)
      }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification) {

    if ( thirdTextField.isFirstResponder()) {
       view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
```